# python pycparser setup error

Tags: python, pip, centos7, pycparser

I am seeing the following error while setting up pyparser on CentOS 7 via pip

```
/usr/bin/python2 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-PMzCYU/pycparser/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-0bpBrX-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile
Traceback (most recent call last):
```

File "", line 1, in init.py", line 12, in 
    import setuptools.version
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/version.py", line 1, in 
    import pkg_resources
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/**init**.py", line 72, in 
    import packaging.requirements
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/packaging/requirements.py", line 59, in 
    MARKER_EXPR = originalTextFor(MARKER_EXPR())("marker")
TypeError: **call**() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)

Comment: This is also affecting `eb deploy` in latest versions of `awsebcli`

Comment: Any resolution?

Answer (score 9):

This appears to be caused by https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/commit/ff371f18f0076bc63da05334f7e551c1cc29e10d which was released in v34.0.0 of setuptools.  This commit removed the vendoring of several packages.  Also looks like this only affects new setuptools installs.  Existing ones are fine on 34.0.2

Work around via hard coding the version:

`pip install setuptools==33.1.1`

Still working out how to fix pip usage once >= 34.0.0 is installed,

EDIT: this is by design
"Setuptools no longer supports self upgrade or installation in the general case."
http://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/history.html#v34-0-0

Comment: Latest versions of the `packaging` and `pyparsing` modules have addressed this problem.

Answer (score 4):

Note: Running Python 2.7.10 on Macbook Yosmite, attempting install of TensorFlow, using pip. Any attempt to install or upgrade "numpy", in order to resolve Tensorflow dependency issue on 'numpy' version, generates error as follows:

```
TypeError: __call__() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)
```

I had installed, via pip, latest Tensorflow, which loaded many packages. This broke pip.  All attempts to run pip generated same errors as post above, with final line being:

```
TypeError: __call__() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)
```

including the `pip install setuptools==33.1.1` suggestion provided above. The TensorFlow install pooched my pip version, bad pyparser code, looks like.  Remember, I'm running Python 2.7.x..

The resolution suggested to `pip install setuptool==33.1.1` generates same error sequence, since the Python 2.7 parser was broken. pip and also easy_install were broken.  I could not even update pip using `get-pip.py`. Running `python get-pip.py` generates essentially the same error sequence shown above.  Really maximal NFG.

[So, the solution...] Found the solution piecing together from other posts: The "requirements.py" (a pyparser prgm?) has an error in it, which can be fixed by finding the code and editing the file. On my Macbook, the file is in: `/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/packaging`

Find the python prgm called: `requirements.py` Change line 59:

```
MARKER_EXPR = originalTextFor(MARKER_EXPR())("marker")
```

To:

```
MARKER_EXPR = originalTextFor(MARKER_EXPR(""))("marker")
```

I've confirmed that this change lets `pip` and `easy_install` run again. Also, on Linux, one could also provoke the error by just running, in Python:

```
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
```

Confirmed that this now works in Python 2.7.10 on Mac OS 10.10.5, after the fix to `requirements.py`.

Comment: Everything python2.7-based was breaking on my macports 2.4.1 installation  on Mac OS 10.11 (I was trying to get salt-cloud running) and this fixed it. Not sure if this is a bug or a config issue with macports, but I'm able to get on with life now.

Comment: `requirements.py` is part of the `packaging` module - latest versions of `packaging` and `pyparsing` have addressed this issue.

Answer (score 0):

same solution worked for me

`pip install setuptools==33.1.1`
and then `sudo pip install -r requirements.txt`